# What's the use of the Sizzle selector engine?

Tags: css, sizzle

I already know how to use the Sizzle CSS selector engine.

This is the syntax: `Sizzle( selector );`

So now my question is: What is the use of the Sizzle CSS selector engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sizzle** is much more lightweight than jQuery. jQuery is an entire DOM manipulation library and sizzle is just a selector engine. jQuery is 80kb gzipped and minified. Sizzle is **50kb uncompressed.**

Comment: Jquery is 28kb when gzipped and minified, 80kb when just minified. Still, sizzle is only 4kb when gzipped and minified

Answer (score 1):

It a core component of the jQuery JavaScript API, and is thus in common use.

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle parses the html elements and find the element you are looking for in a quick and efficient manner.